# How to exclude whole sentences delimited with punctuation?

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex words fine if there's one sentence per line (I want to highlight the sentences that start with those words and end with a period):

`(How|What|Where|Is|Are|Has|Have|Do|Does)(.*)(\.)`

However in lines like these:

```
What something? Is something.
```

The whole line is highlighted. I only want to highlight `Is something.`

I tried this:

```
(?![?!.])(How|What|Where|Is|Are|Has|Have|Do|Does)(.*)(\.)
```

But nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

https://regexr.com/4bdcr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try making replacing your `.*` with `[^.?!]*`, which will not match across full stop *or* any other ending punctuation mark:

```
\b(?:How|What|Where|Is|Are|Has|Have|Do|Does)\b[^.?!]*\.
```

### Demo

Here is a brief JavaScript snippet showing the regex being actually used:

```js
var input = "What something? Is something.";
var regex = /\b((?:How|What|Where|Is|Are|Has|Have|Do|Does)\b[^.?!]*\.)/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this ?

```
[How|Is|Where|What|Are][ \w+]*[\.|\?]
```

Anything that starts with the question word, followed by spaces or words

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negated character class here:

```
/(?:How|What|Where|Is|Are|Has|Have|Do|Does)([^?.\n]*)\./g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BFZh5u/1)

`[^?.\n]` is negated character class that will match any character except `.`, `?` or newline.